# AxisAngleRotation3D to Quaternion gives unexpected result

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, rotation, quaternions

I am developing a controller in WPF 3D (using C#) to be able to easily move and rotate a `ProjectionCamera` using `Move()`- and `Pitch()`-functions. My controller will become a `Behavior<ProjectionCamera>` that can be attached to a `ProjectionCamera`. In order to initialize the controller, I want to **calculate the current rotation** of the camera by looking at its current `Up` and `Forward`-vectors and compare them to the default camera orientation (`Up = [0 1 0]`, `Forward = [0 0 -1]`). In other words, I want to calculate a rotation that will transform the camera default's orientation to its current one.

Ultimately, I want to express the rotation as a single `Quaternion`, but as an intermediate step I first calculate the **Proper Euler Angle rotations** of the form **z-N-Z** expressed as `AxisAngleRotation3D`-values, following the default definition of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles):

```
var alphaRotation = CalculateRotation(z, x, N);
var betaRotation = CalculateRotation(N, z, Z);
var gammaRotation = CalculateRotation(Z, N, X);
```

with

```
CalculateRotation(Vector3D axisOfRotation, Vector3D from, Vector3D to) : AxisAngleRotation3D
```

The Euler Angle Rotations seem to be calculated correctly, based on some unit tests. However, when I convert these rotations to a single `Quaternion`, the resulting `Quaternion` represents a rotation that **differs** from the Euler Angle Rotations, and I don't know why.

This is how I convert the Euler Angles to a single Quaternion:

```
var rotation =
    new Quaternion(alphaRotation.Axis, alphaRotation.Angle) *
    new Quaternion(betaRotation.Axis, betaRotation.Angle) *
    new Quaternion(gammaRotation.Axis, gammaRotation.Angle);
```

For example, when I initialize a `ProjectionCamera` with an `UpDirection` of `[1 0 0]`, meaning it's been rotated 90 degrees around its `LookDirection` axis (`[0 0 -1]`), the calculated Euler Angle Rotations are as follows:

```
alphaRotation -->  90 deg. around [0 1 0]
betaRotation  -->  90 deg. around [0 0 -1]
gammaRotation --> -90 deg. around [1 0 0]
```

My test verifies that, when applied in order, these rotations will transform the default `Up`-vector (`[0 1 0]`) into the current `Up`-vector (`[1 0 0]`), effectively rotating it 90 deg. around the `[0 0 -1]` axis. (It's also reasonable straightforward to verify this by hand.)

However, when I apply the calculated `QuaternionRotation` to the default `Up`-vector, it is transformed to the vector `[-1 0 0]`, which is obviously wrong. I have hard-coded these results within a Unit Test and got the same results:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ConversionTest()
    {
        var vector = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);

        var alphaRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 90);
        var betaRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, -1), 90);
        var gammaRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), -90);

        var a = new Quaternion(alphaRotation.Axis, alphaRotation.Angle);
        var b = new Quaternion(betaRotation.Axis, betaRotation.Angle);
        var c = new Quaternion(gammaRotation.Axis, gammaRotation.Angle);
        var combinedRotation = a * b * c;

        var x = Apply(vector, alphaRotation, betaRotation, gammaRotation);
        var y = Apply(vector, combinedRotation);
    }
```

When you run the test above, you will see that `x` gives you the expected vector (`[1 0 0]`) but `y` will be different, where it should be exactly the same rotation.

What am I missing?

Comment: [Order of rotations matter](https://www.princeton.edu/~naomi/lecture3.pdf).

Comment: @Sinatr: Yes, I know the order of the rotations matter. Did you spot any mistake in my code? Because as far as I know, Euler Angles have to applied in the order (alpha, beta, gamma), and to represent this sequence of rotations as a single Quaternion, you have to multiply the rotations also in this order (alpha * beta * gamma).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Apparantly, the order of the multiplication of the individual `Quaternions` should be reversed. So, to convert Euler Angles (or any set of rotations) into a single `Quaternion` **in .NET** you should do the following:

```
var rotation = gammaRotation * betaRotation * alphaRotation;
```

where `rotation` represents geometrically applying `alphaRotation` first, then `betaRotation` and finally `gammaRotation`. I just wished they had documented this, since the meaning of the order depends on the specific library you are working with....